# CSS transition bug inside anchor (Chrome and IE)

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg, internet-explorer-10, transition

Take a look at this code:

[jsFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/APymW/6/)

I need to wrap a box div containing text and svg images with link anchor    < a > :

```
<a href="#"> 
    <div id="block1">   
       <svg>...</svg>
       <div class="text">...</div>
   </div>
</a>
```

On hover event I want to smoothly change colors of that svg image ( colors of < path > elements )

```
#block1:hover #path1 {
   fill: #color;
   -webkit-transition: 0.8s all ease-in-out;
           .................................
           transition: 0.8s all ease-in-out;
}
```

It all works fine on Firefox (haven't tested Opera or Safari), doesn't work in IE10 and in Chrome there seems to be a strange loading bug:

When I open the jsFiddle page it seems to work, but if I edit the code and run again (without reloading the whole page) the block inside an anchor is flickering (no smooth color transition). If I  reload the whole page again, it works again.

On my project page anchor blocks are flickering on the first load. I've also tried to load my project page locally and there was no flickering.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this (on Chrome at least)? Thank you

EDIT: Found a solution which make the anchor block element absolute instead of wrapping the block:

```
<div id="block1" style="position:relative;>   
   <a href="#" style="position:absolute; display:block; 
               height:200px; width:400px; z-index=1"> </a>
   <svg>...</svg>
   <div class="text">...</div>
</div>
```

Is this acceptable practice ? Still doesnt work on IE10 though..

Comment: Are you expecting your users to reload only the SVG and not the entire page?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. In my project page SVGs don't change, only transitions and animations are applied to them. I'm using these blocks on the first page, they serve as links to other pages. They look a bit like windows metro icons.